# How jump run/execute file2 when a button is pressed from file1 in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gtk, tk-toolkit

I have ***2*** python files **File 1 & File 2** which are coded in tkinter.

**File 1** is `Welcome page` having 1 button Login as doctor.

**File 2** is the `login page` in which doctor will enter his/her credentials.
both the file are coded in **tkinter**

> Running:-

1. Welcome file(file 1) will run in GUI FORM
2. When the button is pressed on the file 1 it should be redirected to
   the login Page (file 2)

> Note:-

Both the file are **different**.

> File 1 Welcome.py

```
#import modules
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import messagebox
import importlib
# creating the object
root = Tk()

# resolution of the window
root.geometry("500x540+500+100")
root.title ("ABC HOSPITAL")

# preventing the resize feature
root.resizable(False, False)
def doc():
    importlib.import_module('login')

#LABELS=====================================================
heading = Label(font=('times new roman' , 25 , 'bold'), text="WELCOME TO ABC HOSPITAL", fg='black', bg='#fbf9d3')
heading.place(x=3, y=10)

heading = Label(font=('times new roman' , 22 , 'bold'), text="Choose Login", fg='black', bg='#fbf9d3')
heading.place(x=150, y=250)
#button to perform a command=======================================================
login = Button(font=('arial' , 20 , 'bold'),bd=14, text="DOCTOR's LOGIN", fg='white',bg='#04062c',width=27,height=2)
login.place(x=4,y=300)

root.mainloop()
```

> File 2 login.py

```
#import modules
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import random
from tkinter import messagebox

# creating the object
root = Tk()

# resolution of the window
root.geometry("1520x790+0+0")
root.title ("ABC HOSPITAL")
root.iconbitmap('hospital.ico')

# preventing the resize feature
root.resizable(False, False)

#tkinter window
class Application:

#funtion for main frames=====================================================================================================================================================================

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        # creating the frames in the master
        self.left = Frame(master, width= 1600, height= 900, bg='lightblue',relief=SUNKEN)
        self.left.pack(side=TOP)

        #Background Picture
        self.photo1 = PhotoImage(file='background.png')
        self.pic = Label(self.left, font=('arial' , 1 , 'bold'), image= self.photo1)
        self.pic.place(x=0, y=0)


#LABELS=====================================================
        self.heading = Label(self.left,font=('arial' , 50 , 'bold'), text="ABC Hospital", fg='black', bg='#06378b' ,anchor='w')
        self.heading.place(x=550, y=0)

        #Login Picture
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file= 'login.png')
        self.pic = Label(self.left, font=('arial' , 40 , 'bold'), image= self.photo ,fg = "lightblue", bg='#06378b')
        self.pic.place(x=640, y=100)

        # user name
        self.username = Label(self.left, text="Username", font=('arial 30 bold'), fg='black', bg='#063998')
        self.username.place(x=550, y=350)

        # password
        self.password = Label(self.left, text="Password", font=('arial 30 bold'), fg='black', bg='#063998')
        self.password.place(x=550, y=410)

#TEXTBOX=====================================================
        #username
        self.username_ent = Entry(self.left,font=('arial' , 20 , 'bold'))
        self.username_ent.place(x=750, y=360)

        #password
        self.password_ent = Entry(self.left, font=('arial' , 20 , 'bold'),show='*')
        self.password_ent.place(x=750, y=420)

# button to perform a command================================
        #button1
        self.login = Button(self.left,font=('arial' , 20 , 'bold'), text="LOGIN", bg='steelblue')
        self.login.place(x=700, y=480)

b = Application(root)                      
root.mainloop()
```

**The button from welcome page is pressed login page should executed in gui form**

**plz help i have a college mini project but i am stuck here....**

Comment: Hi H.Park! Check your button command in login.py , it seems like you want to call the button itself which doesn't make any sense. You probably missing `login()` function in your Application class in file 2

Comment: actually it was a miss type i was trying a lot of things so it stayed by mistake i removed it sorry  ............. do u have any idea how can i solve above problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is definitely not the right way to open a second window from a the main window. In Tkinter if you need addition windows we use `Toplevel()` instead of using another `Tk()`,  though it'll work but not the recommended approach.
2. You don't need `importlib` here, it can done very easily without the use of it.

   Like you can define a function in your file.py, `import file` in your main file then call it with the press of a button in your File 1 by `file.Run_login`

   **Example:**

   File 2

   ```
   def Run_Login():
       # creating the object
       root = Toplevel()

       # resolution of the window
       root.geometry("1520x790+0+0")
       root.title ("ABC HOSPITAL")
       # root.iconbitmap('hospital.ico')

       # preventing the resize feature
       root.resizable(False, False)
       Application(root)
   ```

   File 2:

   ```
   import file

   def doc():
       file.Run_Login(master=root)
   ```
3. Also inheriting Toplevel in your Application class will make your job easier by a lot because then you can just import the class in your File 1 `from file import Application`. Then in doc you can call it.

   **Example:**

   ```
   def doc():
       A = Application(master = root)
   ```

---

### **Complete Code**

**File 1 - Window.py**

```
#import modules
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import messagebox

# Make sure you import name is same as the file name.
from login import Application

# creating the object
root = Tk()

# resolution of the window
root.geometry("500x540+500+100")
root.title ("ABC HOSPITAL")

# preventing the resize feature
root.resizable(False, False)

def doc():
    App = Application(root)

#LABELS=====================================================
heading = Label(font=('times new roman' , 25 , 'bold'), text="WELCOME TO ABC HOSPITAL", fg='black', bg='#fbf9d3')
heading.place(x=3, y=10)

heading = Label(font=('times new roman' , 22 , 'bold'), text="Choose Login", fg='black', bg='#fbf9d3')
heading.place(x=150, y=250)
#button to perform a command=======================================================
login = Button(font=('arial' , 20 , 'bold'),bd=14, text="DOCTOR's LOGIN", 
        fg='white',bg='#04062c',width=27,height=2, command=doc)
login.place(x=4,y=300)

mainloop()
```

---

**File 2 - login.py**

```
#import modules
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import random
from tkinter import messagebox


#tkinter window
class Application(Toplevel):

#funtion for main frames=====================================================================================================================================================================

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        # resolution of the window
        self.geometry("1520x790+0+0")
        self.title ("ABC HOSPITAL")
        self.iconbitmap('hospital.ico')

        # preventing the resize feature
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # creating the frames in the master
        self.left = Frame(self, width= 1600, height= 900, bg='lightblue',relief=SUNKEN)
        self.left.pack(side=TOP)

        #Background Picture
        self.photo1 = PhotoImage(file='background.png')
        self.pic = Label(self.left, font=('arial' , 1 , 'bold'), image= self.photo1)
        self.pic.place(x=0, y=0)


#LABELS=====================================================
        self.heading = Label(self.left,font=('arial' , 50 , 'bold'), text="ABC Hospital", fg='black', bg='#06378b' ,anchor='w')
        self.heading.place(x=550, y=0)

        #Login Picture
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file= 'login.png')
        self.pic = Label(self.left, font=('arial' , 40 , 'bold'), image= self.photo ,fg = "lightblue", bg='#06378b')
        self.pic.place(x=640, y=100)

        # user name
        self.username = Label(self.left, text="Username", font=('arial 30 bold'), fg='black', bg='#063998')
        self.username.place(x=550, y=350)

        # password
        self.password = Label(self.left, text="Password", font=('arial 30 bold'), fg='black', bg='#063998')
        self.password.place(x=550, y=410)

#TEXTBOX=====================================================
        #username
        self.username_ent = Entry(self.left,font=('arial' , 20 , 'bold'))
        self.username_ent.place(x=750, y=360)

        #password
        self.password_ent = Entry(self.left, font=('arial' , 20 , 'bold'),show='*')
        self.password_ent.place(x=750, y=420)

# button to perform a command================================
        #button1
        self.login = Button(self.left,font=('arial' , 20 , 'bold'), text="LOGIN", bg='steelblue')
        self.login.place(x=700, y=480)


if __name__ == "__main__":    
     # Only runs when you run login.py if you import this file whatever after this if statement will not run.
     Application().mainloop()
```

---

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thankxxxx A Lot Saad